# removeAttribute not applying for last element in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of elements that I use to search for the corresponding HTML using JQuery that I then need to remove attributes from. My function looks like this:

```
for (const block of collection) {
            //selectedBlock is returned as an array that I only want the first element of
            const selectedBlock = $('g').find(`[data-type='` + block.attributes.type + `']`)[0];
            selectedBlock.removeAttribute('pointer-events');
            selectedBlock.removeAttribute('opacity');
}
```

The code works for every element in the array except the last one. I've tried to debug it and it runs through the function just fine, but the removed attributes still remain afterwards. If I force an out of bounds error by running the loop collection.length+1 times, it works but then I get the out of bounds error. Why does the function not affect the last element despite the code being executed on it normally?

Edit:

I made a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1w04y6kr/4/ with all the basic components of what I'm trying to do (some <g>s with the attributes data-type/pointer-events/opacity, and some code to find the first of each data-type and remove the attributes). This example works 100%, but the same logic is in my project and it's still just not removing pointer-events/opacity from only the last element of `collection`

**Update**

@Wimanicesir was correct, the problem was somewhere else in the project (a seemingly unrelated area too, will have to investigate that) that was adding the attributes back to the last element after executing the above code. A simple reordering of functions fixed it.

Comment: Please post some sample data HTML, so we can test this. Minimal, Reproducible Example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Based off your story and your logic. Your mistake is probably not visible in the code you now posted.

Comment: Is the element being found? Console log and check if you get something or just null

Comment: @ikiK Note that you can use the magic link `[mre]` to produce text and link like [mre] in your comments.

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide HTML (and SVG) along with CSS and JavaScript in a runnable snippet that others can then copy to their answers, modify so they work, and present you with working code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Awesome, thanks.

Comment: @ImmortalDude I can see the element in the console and I can debug line by line to see that it is indeed executing where I need it to, but the end result is unaffected by the code.

Comment: @Wimanicesir You were right, it had something to do with other functions that executed after my code, don't exactly know why they affected it but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach. With HTML / SVG / XML like this:

```
<g data-type='type1' pointer-events='none' opacity='0.8'>Example 1</g>
<g data-type='type2' pointer-events='none' opacity='0.8'>Example 1</g>
<g data-type='type1' pointer-events='none' opacity='0.8'>Example 1</g>
```

```js
const collection = ['type1', 'type2'];

collection.forEach(blockType =>
  $(`g[data-type="${blockType}"]`)
    .removeAttr('pointer-events')
    .removeAttr('opacity')
);
```

Usually in HTML, `pointer-events` and `opacity` would be CSS, not HTML properties. If so, use:

```js
collection.forEach(blockType =>
  $(`g[data-type="${blockType}"]`).css({
    'pointer-events': 'initial',
    'opacity': 'initial',
  })
);
```

Comment: `g` is an SVG element, not HTML; I'm not an expert in SVG, but I've seen enough to say a lot of CSS properties become attributes (e.g., `fill="#000000"` sets the CSS `fill` property to `#000000`).

Comment: Good point, if it's about attributes of `<g>`, just use the `.removeAttr()`.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Unfortunately it gives me the same result, only the last element still has the attributes that are supposed to be removed

Comment: I've edited the answer. See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gn6kwrdb/